# Can I modify fileLocation for problemMatcher?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-problem-matcher

I'm using `Make` over SSH to invoke `gcc`.
I have mirrored source files in my local computer for editing.
After editing, it is synchronized with SFTP.

The problem is when the ProblemMatcher is set to `$gcc`, 
it returns full path of remote server, so it can't be matched with local files.

Local File:
`~/foo/bar.c`  (= /home/user/foo/bar.c)

Remote File:
`~/foo/bar.c` (= /datavolume/foo/bar.c)

problemMatcher tries to find bar.c at
`/home/user/datavolume/foo/bar.c` resulted in **file not found**

`fileLocation` has two options `relative`, `absolute` but neither resolves this issue.

With `relative`, I can only use `..` for local location only. I can't trim remote location.

With `absolute`, I am not sure how to use it but it still can't find local location under WSL(Bash on Windows) directory.

`absolute` also fails.

```
"fileLocation":
[
  "absolute",
"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\\LocalState\\rootfs\\home\\user\\foo"
]
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem and filed an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57015)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74706156/836330 for a new `search` `fileLocation` option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `regexp` to subtract `/datavolume/` and use `relative` like that:

```
"problemMatcher": {
    "owner": "cpp",
    "fileLocation": [
        "relative",
        "${workspaceFolder}"
    ],
    "pattern": {
        "regexp": "^\\/datavolume\\/(\\S+):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
        "file": 1,
        "line": 2,
        "column": 3,
        "severity": 4,
        "message": 5
    }
}
```